# find and replace a string in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with 3 string columns.
'author', 'title' and 'mytext'

I need to find a string (for e.g. question mark ?) and replace it (for e.g. period .) across all records ('mytext' column). There are only 300 records in the table.

I am looking for an easy way to find - replace text using python.

---

I am using this code that is working as expected.
Are there any surprises / issues expected in the future? I guess for 300 records, it should be OK.

```py
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', aws_access_key_id="xxx", aws_secret_access_key="xxx", region_name='us-east-1' )
table = dynamodb.Table('table-test')

response = table.scan()
data = response['Items']
    
for item in data:
    if item["mytext"] != item["mytext"].replace("?", "."):
        updated_data = {
            'author': item["author"] ,
            'title': item["title"] ,
            'mytext': item["mytext"].replace("?", ".")
        }
        table.put_item(Item=updated_data)
```

Comment: Is it possible to edit the exported to S3  backup copy and then import it?

Comment: 'author' is the partition key and 'title' is the sort key.

Comment: `PutItem` is an overwrite, you should use `UpdateItem`

Comment: I am aware that PutItem is an overwrite. My question: Is there any problem in overwriting an item of a small table? And is it going to be costly once I have a million records?

Comment: Yes there's a problem, you're overwriting it when you only want to update some values.

Comment: Got it. Update query looked complicated compared to overwrite. But that is the correct way for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample snippet that scans the entire table and replaces all occurrences of the question mark character with a period.

Note that, given your current structure (with "author" as the partition key and "title" as the sort key), you can only update the "mytext" field. This is because key parts cannot be modified.

```py
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table-test')

def replace_question_mark():
    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']
    
    for item in data:
        table.update_item(
            Key={'author': item["author"], 'title': item["title"]},
            UpdateExpression="set mytext=:m",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={':m': item["mytext"].replace("?", ".")},
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW")
```

Be aware that a full scan can be very expensive (both computationally and in terms of costs). Use it at your own risk!

Comment: Got an error - KeyError: 'id'

Comment: You should replace the “id” key in update_item with your actual key field.

Comment: `AttributeUpdates` is legacy and should not be used.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan sorry, you're right, I've updated the answer with `UpdateExpression` instead.

Comment: Should I use "author" or / and "title" as key?

Comment: @shantanuo both, but note that you cannot modify them because they're part of the key. Answer updated with your actual table structure.

Comment: Is there any way to know how many rows were updated?

Answer (score 1):

For 300 items you can just [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) the table, use a FilterExpression and `contains` function to state what you're looking for. Once you get the results, loop through them and call UpdateItem.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression

Comment: Updated the question. I am using this code that is working as expected. Are there any surprises / issues expected in the future? I guess for 300 records, it should be OK.

Comment: Yes, you should use UpdateItem instead of PutItem

Comment: Trying to know more about the problems I may face if I keep using PutItem instead of Update. The frequency of the find-replace activity is going to be once or twice every year. And the table is not expected to grow.

Comment: If I use UpdateItem is there any way to know how many rows were updated?